# How to expose port 80 for Node cartridge on Openshift?

Tags: node.js, express, port, openshift

On Openshift, a Node cartridge is exposed on OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT, which defaults to port 8080. Is it possible to also expose port 80 for the same app? One at a time, or both at the same time, doesn't matter.

If I call the app on port 8080, I can reach it. If I call it on port 80, I get no response. In the app, I bind to OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT (8080). What do I need to do to access the app on port 80?

Comment: OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT is the port you have to bind to, but it will be served as port 80 by the Apache reverse proxy that sits in front of your application.

Comment: You might also try reading through this article on port binding and routing on openshift: https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-port-binding-routing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port 8080 re-routes externally through port 80. It's not possible to expose port 80 on the app. Check out [Binding Applications to Ports](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/OpenShift_Online/2.0/html/User_Guide/sect-Binding_Applications_to_Ports.html) in the documentation.

Most relevant notes from the doc:

> All ports less than 1024 are reserved for OpenShift Online operations, and developers cannot bind to these ports. However, ports greater than 1024 are available for binding, and the following table shows the commonly used ports.
>
> ...
>
> Ports 15000 - 35530 are available for binding internal IP, but these ports are not externally addressable. You can also bind to `$OPENSHIFT_Cart_Name_PORT` (8080) for HTTP connectivity, which reroutes externally through port 80.